# Почему не работает e.preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему в `ei11` форма делает перезагрузку, хотя прописал preventDefault, только в `ie` такой баг:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  if (!validateForm(inputs)) {
    if (event.preventDefault) {
      console.log('test5')
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      console.log('test6')

      event.returnValue = false;
    }
  } else {
    showSuccess(form);
    if (event.preventDefault) {
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      console.log('test7')

      event.returnValue = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ну так надо возвратить `false` что-то вроде `return false;`. А так в IE все работает норм вроде. С `event.returnValue` предлагаю не заморачиваться, это уже глубокое legacy. А вот про третий параметр `addEventListener` вы зря забываете.

Comment: @DiD вот так? 

form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            if (!validateForm(inputs)) {
                event.preventDefault()
                return false
            } else {
                showSuccess(form);
                event.preventDefault()
                return false
            }
        }, false);

Comment: точку с запятой между preventDefault и return false в двух местах

Comment: @DiD спасибо, помогло, сделает ответ, поставлю что он правильный